# Jpa Many-To-Many relationship fails with inheritance

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, inheritance, jpa

first of all I use:

-Eclipse Kepler

-JPA 2.1

-MySql 5.1

-MySql connector 5.1

-EclipseLink 2.5

4 classes are involved:

-a normal class involved in a many-to-many relationship (i won't post the code of this)
-an abstract class (it contains just a thisId field)
-a normal class which inherits from the previous one
-another normal class which inherits from the other normal class

Here is the code of the last 2 classes

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class MyObject extends AbstractObject implements Serializable {

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

private String descr;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "relation",
        joinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "thisId", referencedColumnName = "thisId"),
        inverseJoinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "otherId", referencedColumnName = "otherId"))
    private List<OtherClass> listHoldingTheRelationship;
// Getters and setters, other methods
}
```

The many-to-many has only owning side, so there are no special annotation in the OtherClass involved
Here is the code of the last class:

```
public class MyObjectPers extends MyObject implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int field;
//getters setter, other methods
}
```

When I try to create a MyObjectPers i get this:

```
12:02:33    INSERT INTO `myDB`.`relation` (`otherId`, `thisId`) VALUES ("209",
"888")  Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
constraint fails (`mydb`.`relation`, CONSTRAINT `FK_PKG_ESC_thisId` FOREIGN KEY
(`thisId`) REFERENCES `MyObjectPers` (`thisId`))    0.015 sec
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: don't feel shy of posting all the classes involved, even if they look trivial. They are all necessary parts for us to help you. Even the code that you create the entity and tries to persist.

Comment: Looking into the error it sounds you are trying to persist a parent with a child but that child is not in the database, so when you tried to insert the reference to the child the error comes. Try to persist the child to the database first.  But I'm agree with Leo, please add more source code.

Comment: problem solved, koitoer was right, thanks